# How to work with numbers of the order 10^100 in C & java?

Tags: java, c

How to work with numbers of the order 10^100?Like iterating upto a number of that order,getting sum of squares of their digits;then checking if the sum matches the square of a certain number,if yes sum up those numbers and finally display the sum of those numbers.

Comment: Java has a class called `BigInteger`.

Comment: Iterating up to 10^100? Even if iteration is taking 1nSec, it will be 10^91 seconds. about 10^86 years.. Hm.

Comment: You can't iterate to a number that large, you have to use a formula which calculates the result in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily handle this kind of task with strings containing the decimal representation of the numbers.

The sum of squares of the digits of a 100 digit number is bounded by `100*9^2 = 8100`: you can use `int` for that.

Comment: It will take longer than the age of the universe to iterate to that number however ;)

Comment: **very much** longer

Comment: @PeterLawrey: It actually depends how the iteration is performed: if large chunks are skipped at a time, it may bring it down to a more manageable timeframe.